# Difference between YouTube API results and actual YouTube queries?

Tags: php, xml, youtube, youtube-api

I'm creating a php script that involves parsing some data from the youtube api.

this is the query I'm running:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=science&max-results=25&fields=entry[media:group/yt:duration/@seconds > 1200 and yt:statistics/@viewCount > 20]
```

For whatever reason, I only get 3 results from this. You would expect far far more results than that. Additionally, if I manually go to youtube and search for the same criteria ("science" for a search word and at least 20 minutes long), you get pages full of results.

Why am I only getting 3?

This repeats itself with multiple queries; there's only a tiny number in the data set returned by the API but there's pages and pages of results for the regular query at the actual youtube search page.

My previous topic was closed, however at the Youtube API Developer Forum it states stackoverflow is where I should direct my questions-- if it isn't appropriate here, then where should I go for an answer?

Comment: I suggest you to grab from the actual YouTube.. I was working with those APIs once and it ended up with false/late results, i was searching for 3 hours for the error in the code then i realized that the API was getting unreal results.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Use `&v=2` to use version 2 of the API, which is much more robust.
- Version 2 also introduced a Duration parameter, which is more effective than yt:duration bit you've got in the Fields parameter.

The query can be made much more robust by doing (broken up for readability, since I assume this query is being generated somewhat programmatically).

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?
q=science
&max-results=25
&duration=long
&fields=entry[yt:statistics/@viewCount%20%3E%2020]
&v=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, to answer your question as to why you're only getting back 3 results, see my comment here: [syntax for multiple field/entry specifications in the youtube api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442273/syntax-for-multiple-field-entry-specifications-in-the-youtube-api#comment18413552_13443706)